# Updating the UUID of a client in PubNub

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I am writing a simple chat application using PubNub to demo realtime data. When the application starts it shows a list of connected users down the side. Each user has a default UUID that is generated by PubNub when initialised. I want to be able to change this UUID to something more human friendly. I am aware that I can do this when I initialise the PubNub library

```
PubNub.init({
  ... keys ...
  uuid: 'The username'
});
```

But I wish to also do this 'on the fly' so users can update their username during the runtime of the application. I have not been able to find any documentation to support this functionality which suggests to me it is not possible. However I also see nothing stating it cannot be done. Is there such a feature and how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Changing the UUID in PubNub

You can change the UUID of a connected client anytime.  Use the `set_uuid` method to update the UUID and have the SDK re-initialize the Connection State with a new UUID.

### Set initial UUID

```
var pubnub = PUBNUB({ ..., uuid : "CLIENT_UUID" });
```

### Change the UUID

```
pubnub.set_uuid("NEW_UUID");
```

The only reference currently posted on PubNub Documentation is here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-cpp/api-reference#init_example_3 in the PubNub POSIX C API Reference.

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Would you also be able to post a link to the documentation.

Comment: Posting link shortly -> https://www.pubnub.com/docs/posix-cpp/api-reference#init_example_3

Comment: Fantastic. I really struggled finding that.

Comment: Same here.  I looked at the [PubNub SDK source code](https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-dev.js) to find the method.